# getsockname always returning 0.0.0.0?

Tags: c, sockets, networking

Here is the code. It is the same as the code from this similar question: http://monkey.org/freebsd/archive/freebsd-stable/200401/msg00032.html. When I run it I always get the output:

listening on 0.0.0.0:54493 or something. Obviously the port changes, but I have no idea why I keep getting an IP address of 0.0.0.0. Am I missing something?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main()
{
    int sock;
    int len = sizeof(struct sockaddr);
    struct sockaddr_in addr, foo;

    if((sock=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))<0)
    {
        exit(0);
    }

    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    addr.sin_port = htons(0);

    if(bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in))<0)
    {
        perror("bind");
        exit(0);
    }

    if(listen(sock, 5)<0)
    {
         perror("listen");
         exit(0);
    }

    getsockname(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &foo, &len);
    fprintf(stderr, "listening on %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(foo.sin_addr), 
            ntohs(foo.sin_port));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You specify `INADDR_ANY` rather than a specific IP address, so it binds to the wildcard (all interfaces) `0.0.0.0`. So, when you call `getsockname()` that's what you get back.

If you specified `0.0.0.0` as the IP address rather than `INADDR_ANY` you would get the same behavior; you will bind to all network interfaces on the machine.

For example, lets say you only have one network interface with the IP `192.168.1.12` assigned to it. You also have the loopback by default - `127.0.0.1`

Using `0.0.0.0` or `INADDR_ANY` means you'll be bound to both those addresses, rather than a specific one. You will be able to connect to to your process via either IP.

If you were to bind to a specific IP rather than `INADDR_ANY`, your process would only listen on that IP and you'd get back that specific IP with `getsockname()`.

Comment: So how do you specify that you don't want 0.0.0.0?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you bind it to a LOOPBACK , u have to specify INADDR_LOOPBACK.
Otherwise it attaches itself to 0.0.0.0 which represents all the network interfaces available. I was facing the same problem, while issuing getnameinfo() call.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other answers, `0.0.0.0` is returned because `INADDR_ANY` was specified as the host address for the listening socket.  This makes sense if you think that, in a multi-homed host, client connections could come in on any of those interfaces (so which should be reported?)

Expanding on those answers; if the actual IP address of a client connection is required, use the `SOCKET` returned from `accept()` with `getsockname()`.  This will provide the interface address on the server to which the client connected.